# Prepend/Append content to a MVC FileStreamResult

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, filestream

I'm re-factoring some code which uses an handler (ashx) to use an MVC `FileStreamResult` instead.

The code returns json, but wraps it in a callback if jsonp is requested.
(callback is a string some thing similar to "jQuery1112077" etc)

```
//existing
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/javascript");
            if (format == "json")
            {
                context.Response.WriteFile(jsonFilePath);
            }

            if (format == "jsonp")
            {
                context.Response.Write(callback + "(");
                context.Response.WriteFile(jsonFilePath);
                context.Response.Write(")");
            }

//MVC
            if (format == "json")
            {
                Stream stream = new FileStream(jsonDocPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                FileStreamResult fs = new FileStreamResult(stream, "text/javascript");
                return fs;
            }
```

What is the most efficient "MVC" way of prepending and appending to the output stream for my jsonp case.